# scipy.integrate.solve_ivp unclear how to solve implicit ODE of form 0=F(t, y(t), y'(t))

Tags: python, scipy

Currently, I do use [assimulos solver suite](https://jmodelica.org/assimulo/tutorial_imp.html) to solve an implicit differential equation of the form 0 = F(t, y(t), y'(t)). I would like to use a solver which comes with a native scipy installation and had a look at the documentation for [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://jmodelica.org/assimulo/tutorial_imp.html). The documentation says that the solver solves a a system of the form:

> Solve an initial value problem for a system of ODEs.
>   This function numerically integrates a system of ordinary differential equations given an initial value `dy / dt = f(t, y)`    `y(t0) = y0`

I do miss the ability to solve a system of the form `dy / dt = f(t, y, y')`. Is this possible with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` ?

Comment: Assuming that `y' = dy / dt`, what is the point of having `y'` on both sides of the equation in `dy / dt = f(t, y, y')`? Can't you just solve for `y'`?

Comment: It might be possible. However the system might change slightly (depending on users choices) and It is not feasible to do this every time. Furthermore, It is a system of equations with several `y'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an equation is called a [differential algebraic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations) (DAE). As far as I know, SciPy doesn't have a built-in DAE solver.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23580269/857390) to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23578596/857390) provides an example of using `fsolve` to solve the algebraic part of the problem in combination with `odeint`. This might be applicable to your problem.

You might also be interested in the [ODES package](https://github.com/bmcage/odes), which provides additional solvers as an extension for SciPy, including a DAE solver.