# Coupling a bvp differential equation with two non linear equations in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I am new to python.
I have a system of 3 equations (variables are y1,y2,y3) :-

`1. y1+y2=5,
  2. d2y3/dx2= (y1/y3)**2, y(0)=y(1)=1,
  3. y1= y3*(exp(y2)+exp(-y2))`

All the functions y1,y2 and y3 are functions of x in [0,1].The second equation is a boundary value problem with the boundary values specified. The first and third equations are non linear equations having implicit relationship between them. I can solve boundary value problems using the bvp solver in python. I can also solve a set of non linear equations in python using the fsolve function. But my problem requires a combination of both the techniques because eqn 2 is a bvp problem and eqns 1 and 3 are non linear implicit equations. I am not being able to couple both the techniques in python. Any help regarding the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few things missing, but I suppose `y1, y2, y3` are all functions in [0,1]?

Comment: Yes, y2 and y3 are also functions of x in [0,1]

Comment: Well, this is a Partial Differential Algebraic Equation(PDAE), which is a lot (!!!!) more complicated to solve than a BVP. If you are lucky, it might work to substitute `y2 = 5 - y1` into the last equation and then somehow try to express `y1` in terms of `y3`, so that you can recover a simple BVP. If not you'll probably have to look into some PDAE resp. DAE solver.

Comment: Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578596/solve-an-implicit-ode-differential-algebraic-equation-dae  seems somewhat related and might give you some ideas on where to find tools.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it and get back here again.